# How to restore scheduler tasks in Python after restarting in telegram bot?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, telegram, apscheduler, aiogram

I’m writing telegram bot and in some places, for instance, user bought a subscription and after a month scheduler has to turn off it, but after reboot all data from RAM will be deleated and this tasks won’t be finished. I use AsyncIOScheduler. After restarting the code I need to continue all scheduled tasks. I tried it, start scheduler, after I restarted the code added in beginning scheduler.start() to continue scheduler tasks from db, but this doesn’t work.

```
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

def f():
    print("Hello, World!")

jobstore = {
"default": SQLAlchemyJobStore(url="sqlite:///scheduler.db")
}

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(jobstores=jobstore)

@router.message(CommandStart())
async def start_handler(message: Message):
    scheduler.add_job(f, "date", id="job_1", jobstore="default", run_date=(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)))
    scheduler.start()
```

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful to set automatically turn off subscription, for instance, but sometimes it’s necessary to restart your code. I’ve found decision.

```
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy      import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

def f():
    print("Hello, World!")

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(jobstores=jobstore)
scheduler.add_jobstore(“sqlalchemy”, url=“sqlite:///scheduler.db”)
scheduler.start()
@router.message(CommandStart())
async def start_handler(message: Message):
    scheduler.add_job(f, "date", id="job_1", run_date=(datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=30)), misfire_grace_time=3600)
```

When you initialise Scheduler object, after it add scheduler.start() to automatically start planned functions. Also add misfire_grace_time argument, for instance, your function has to work on period of time when your code stopped. After reloading it will automatically called even if time has expired